# Kernel initialisation error

Tags: 16.04, boot, grub2, kernel, init

[List of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCmYw.jpg)

I updated my kernel to the latest version on my ubuntu 16.04.3 and now after reboot i get these errors. Please solve.

Comment: How did you "update" your kernel?

Comment: The third line has the key information you should search for. "tried to update" implies that you believe you failed - please edit your question to elaborate.

Comment: I updated the kernel by downloading the .deb files from the net by wget command in the temp folder and then installed it using "sudo dpkg -i *.deb" command. @fkraiem

Comment: There are a lot of `.deb` files on "the net"...

Comment: $ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14/linux-headers-4.14.0-041400_4.14.0-041400.201711122031_all.deb
$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14/linux-headers-4.14.0-041400-generic_4.14.0-041400.201711122031_amd64.deb
$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14/linux-image-4.14.0-041400-generic_4.14.0-041400.201711122031_amd64.deb I downloaded them and then installed through dpkg command @fkraiem

Comment: Please visit the "list of errors" link above in the question to see the errors i get while booting.. I just want to go back to the default version if that is possible. Thank you

Comment: @user535733 Where should i run the command init=option ?

Comment: Look up how to show the GRUB menu at boot. Select your previous kernel at the grub menu. If needed, you run the command init=option at the GRUB command line. Don't upgrade your kernel that way again.

Comment: Please edit the question to add the commands you ran so that the information is readily available to the reader. (I don't know why this kernel does not work on your system, but it's probably wise to remove it and stick with the official kernels.)

Comment: By the way, the latest released version is not 4.14, it is [4.14.6](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14.6/). Just for kicks, I tried installing it on my 17.10 system, where it worked fine.

Comment: The mainline kernel is provided as is for testing only and is not supported. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds "These kernels are not supported and are not appropriate for production use." . A better question is what problem are you having that you feel you need to run the mainline kernel ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `apt` to install and to update software (and the kernel).

Boot from your older kernel by selecting "advanced options" from the `grub` menu.

If the `grub` menu does not display on your computer when you boot, you should hold down your <kbd>shift</kbd> key when you boot to display the `grub` menu.

**The following assumes that you did not download and install nvidia drivers from the internet. If you did manually download and install nvidia drivers from the internet, please let me know and I will post different instructions.**

After you boot up using the older kernel, you can update the kernel and your software by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

As an Ubuntu user, you should try to drop the habit of downloading-an-exe-file and installing it. Remember, this isn't windows. Using `apt` and the `software-center` to install and download stuff for you helps to prevent viruses and malicious code from being injected into your software.

Think of `apt` and the `software-center` like the "google-play" of Ubuntu or the "i-store" or whatever they call it on apple.